# Show items checked on same page using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Javascript Noob here, trying to learn how to write code in plain javascript using no libraries or frameworks. I'm at a lost for how to display the values of the checked items in a div above the form as well as display the checked values on another page using querystrings URLSearchParams. Thanks in advance for helping me. Hopefully I can pay-it-forward when I finally learn javascript. Here is what I have so far:

```
<form>
<div id="myToys" >
  <input type="checkbox" id="v1" name="toy[]" value="Car">
  <label for="toy1"> Car</label><br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="v2" name="toy[]" value="boat">
  <label for="toy2"> Boat</label><br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="v3" name="toy[]" value="Airplane">
  <label for="toy3"> Airplane</label><br><br>
</div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="myFunction()">

</form>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    const myToys = document.getElementById("myToys");
    const chkd = document.getElementsByName("toy").checked;
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "You selected: " + chkd;
    }

function qstrings(){
var myToys= "";

// URL Parameters
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append("myToys", JSON.stringify(myToys));

var url = "page2.html?" + params.toString();
location.href = url;
window.open(url);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Here is the code I'm working on for the querystrings: ```

Answer (score 0):

You had a few issues:

- Missing a "show" element
- `<input>` fields don't have `onsubmit` property; that should be on the `<form>` element
- `onsubmit` handler should `return false` to prevent the form from submitting if you want to show the info on the page
- No need for `const myToys = document.getElementById("myToys");`
- `document.getElementsByName("toy").checked` won't work since there are no elements named 'toy', but rather 'toy[]'. To get the checked ones, you can't simply append `.checked` to your function call.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const myToys = document.querySelectorAll("input:checked");
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = 'You selected: ';
  let a = []
  myToys.forEach(function(e){
    a.push(e.value);
  })
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML += a.join(', ')
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="myFunction(); return false;">
  <div id="myToys" >
    <input type="checkbox" id="v1" name="toy[]" value="Car">
    <label for="toy1"> Car</label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="v2" name="toy[]" value="boat">
    <label for="toy2"> Boat</label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="v3" name="toy[]" value="Airplane">
    <label for="toy3"> Airplane</label><br><br>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="show"></div>
```